# Is these libraries installed right?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I've tried to install python with command
`pip install matplotlib tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 open3d==0.9 sklearn Pillow gdown plyfile`
on the conda environment.
During the process, these wranings came up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGnO2.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95NPM.jpg)
But it was in the middle of the installation, so I don't know which libraries go wrong.

so after the pip install process, I tried to figure which libraries that I need to reinstall, and it said that all requirements are all satisfied. I am wondering whether there is some part that I've done wrong.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know which libraries go wrong

The first error message is about `pywinpty` because it happens while installing `pywinpty`, also the working directory (`cwd`) contains `pywinpty`.

The second one says "the `sklearn` PyPI package is deprecated, use `scikit-learn` rather than `sklearn` for pip commands", so it concerns the `sklearn` library.

If I were you, I'd uninstall both `sklearn` and `pywinpty` (if it somehow was semi-installed) and install Rust (as the first error message suggests) and reinstall `pywinpty` and `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Do you think it's convenient that showing me the terminal code that could install the Rust? Because I was worried about the version that couldn't match. Thanks

Comment: @WonderWu, the error message says you should go to https://rustup.rs and follow the instructions there to install Rust.